# emacs compilation: call a script in background

Tags: bash, emacs, compile-mode

I have a script (let's call it `ding`) which plays a sound in the background (essentially just calls `paplay <file> &`).  I wish to call this from emacs after I finish compiling something, like so:

`M-x compile`, `make && ding`

Unfortunately because `paplay` is called in the background, nothing happens (no sound is played).  If I remove the `&` from `ding`, the sound is played just fine.

Why does this happen, and is there a way to get a script to execute in the background in compilation mode (without making it a foreground job)?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you call it straight from bash, rather than through emacs?

Comment: bash works fine.  M-x shell-command also works, but doesn't do the compilation mode that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs will close the commands' output when the commands finish, and chances are `paplay` doesn't like that. Try `nohup paplay ... &`